# Skip to long lines in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, csv

How do I skip lines, that are to long, when using

```
\addplot
```

command and data read from csv file? My database has around 500k points describing position in x-y space. Position can be wrapped around (transfered from one border to another border), creating such mess (horizontal and vertical lines), when making usual plot:

[image: Wrapped around lines]

How do I prevent it from happening? Splitting file to several ones is not an option, since I have several plots, with many 'transferring lines'. Using

```
only marks
```

doesn't help either, because it creates to big spaces between dots:

[image]

Comment: I think that automatically detect the wraps is almost impossible. So you can manually split the data (maybe with a MATLAB or Python script) or use a bigger mark with `only marks` (btw, I do not dislike that diagram).

Comment: You might use two y scales: one from -500 to 100 and one from 100 to 500.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with partial solution. It simply iterate over every single row and compare it with previous one, drawing it only, if coordinates doesn't wrap around. However, it's not the fastest one (actually, it's slow as hell). Also, it doesn't support smooth lines yet, so if anyone knows better one, please share.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    height=12cm,
    width=12cm,
    xmin=-500,
    xmax=500,
    ymin=-500,
    ymax=500,
]
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{plots/random_walk_perlin_state.csv}{\mytable};

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mytable};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rows}{\pgfplotsretval};

\pgfmathsetmacro{\xnlast}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ynlast}{0}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\xn}{0}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yn}{0}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\len}{100}

\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {0,1,...,\rows-1}
{
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{Pos.x}\of{\mytable}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xn}{\pgfplotsretval}
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{Pos.y}\of{\mytable}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yn}{\pgfplotsretval}

    \pgfmathparse{ abs(\xnlast-\xn) < \len ? (abs(\ynlast-\yn) < \len ? 1 : 0) : 0}
    \ifthenelse{\pgfmathresult > 0}
    {
        \edef\temp
        {
            \noexpand
            \draw (\xnlast,\ynlast) -- (\xn,\yn);
        }
        \temp
    };

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xnlast}{\xn}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ynlast}{\yn}

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```